# How to get COMDAT Symbol from ELF?

Tags: c, elf

I'm trying to get COMDAT Symbol of a section, I read the ELF Format Documentation but couldn't figure out how to do that.

How I identify it is a COMDAT section and get the symbol of it?

***My Code:***

```
typedef struct
{
   unsigned char    e_ident[EI_NIDENT]; /* Magic number and other info */
   Elf32_Half   e_type;         /* Object file type */
   Elf32_Half   e_machine;      /* Architecture */
   Elf32_Word   e_version;      /* Object file version */
   Elf32_Addr   e_entry;        /* Entry point virtual address */
   Elf32_Off    e_phoff;        /* Program header table file offset */
   Elf32_Off    e_shoff;        /* Section header table file offset */
   Elf32_Word   e_flags;        /* Processor-specific flags */
   Elf32_Half   e_ehsize;       /* ELF header size in bytes */
   Elf32_Half   e_phentsize;        /* Program header table entry size */
   Elf32_Half   e_phnum;        /* Program header table entry count */
   Elf32_Half   e_shentsize;        /* Section header table entry size */
   Elf32_Half   e_shnum;        /* Section header table entry count */
   Elf32_Half   e_shstrndx;     /* Section header string table index */
} Elf32_Ehdr;

typedef struct
{
   Elf32_Word   sh_name;        /* Section name (string tbl index) */
   Elf32_Word   sh_type;        /* Section type */
   Elf32_Word   sh_flags;       /* Section flags */
   Elf32_Addr   sh_addr;        /* Section virtual addr at execution */
   Elf32_Off    sh_offset;      /* Section file offset */
   Elf32_Word   sh_size;        /* Section size in bytes */
   Elf32_Word   sh_link;        /* Link to another section */
   Elf32_Word   sh_info;        /* Additional section information */
   Elf32_Word   sh_addralign;       /* Section alignment */
   Elf32_Word   sh_entsize;     /* Entry size if section holds table */
} Elf32_Shdr;

typedef struct
   {
       Elf32_Word   st_name;        /* Symbol name (string tbl index) */
       Elf32_Addr   st_value;       /* Symbol value */
       Elf32_Word   st_size;        /* Symbol size */
       unsigned char    st_info;        /* Symbol type and binding */
       unsigned char    st_other;       /* Symbol visibility */
       Elf32_Section    st_shndx;       /* Section index */
   } Elf32_Sym;
```

Comment: What kind of file are you looking for a COMDAT section in?

Answer (score 0):

I can answer the first question of identification of COMDAT section. the COMDAT section can be identified by its relevant section name i.e. *sh_name*.

COMDAT Section

COMDAT sections are uniquely identified by their section name (sh_name). If the link-editor encounters multiple sections of type SHT_SUNW_COMDAT, with the same section name, the first section is retained and the rest discarded. Any relocations that are applied to a discarded SHT_SUNW_COMDAT section are ignored. Any symbols that are defined in a discarded section are removed.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/819-0690/chapter7-11598.html defines the COMDAT as below (copied w/o alteration)

Additionally, the link-editor supports the section naming convention that is used for section reordering when the compiler is invoked with the -xF option. If a function is placed in a SHT_SUNW_COMDAT section that is named .sectname%funcname, the final SHT_SUNW_COMDAT sections that are retained are coalesced into the section that is named .sectname. This method can be used to place SHT_SUNW_COMDAT sections into the .text, .data, or any other section as their final destination.